# Behaviour of OS-X Application Bundles

Tags: macos, executable, osx-mountain-lion, nsbundle

How does being inside an application bundle affect how the binary executable runs?

To explain, I compiled Emacs for Mountain Lion. This produces a binary executable, and also an application bundle, Emacs.app, that contains the exact same binary (same content, according to diff), plus other resources.

If I run the binary itself from the terminal (or finder):

- Emacs starts, processes my init file correctly and looks good.
- But the application menu still says "Terminal" and
- keyboard input goes to the terminal not to Emacs.
- Also the red traffic-light button gets sent to Emacs (Emacs says it has nothing to save) but does not terminate the process.

In contrast, if I run the Emacs.app, Emacs runs as expected. Can anyone explain this difference for me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you launch an .app bundle, the Info.plist at the root of the folder configures many OS specific behaviors.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Introduction/Introduction.html

You can launch *any* native executable this way and have the same behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll read it now. But when you say 'any', there are executables that don't behave that way. For example I have Gimp (gimp-2.8: Mach-O 64-bit executable) and running that from the shell works as I would expect an app to work. What is the difference here?

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from specifying most (if not all) behaviors conventionally configured in the Info.plist in the executable.

Comment: Ah, ok, so the Emacs people spent the necessary effort to create the application bundle, whilst the gimp people coded the equivalent operations into the executable. Understand now, thanks.